# JPA Hibernate + MEDIUMBLOB

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Добрый день. Проблема следующая: есть три hibernate сущности: customer, order, photo. У заказчика есть заказы и есть одно фото. Фото состоит из long id, byte[]data(mediumblob), Customer customer. Все работает. Нужно теперь к заказу еще счет прикрутить (long id,byte[]data(mediumblob),Ord ord) - т.е. то же самое, что и фото. Но, как только я добавляю данную сущность таблица заказов перестает создаваться и "ERROR". Что неправильно? Спасибо.
Update: ошибка возникает, только если добавить связь между заказом и счетом, посему уточняю вопрос. Есть-ли ограничение по количеству колонок(у заказа 8 колонок без данной сущности) или по количеству дополнительных таблиц?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class Ord {
@Id
@Expose
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
@Expose
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "product")
private Product product;
@Expose
@Column(nullable = false)
private String buyer;
@Expose
private long orderTime;
@Expose
private long deliveryTime;
@Expose
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customer")
private Customer customer;
@Expose
@JoinColumn(name = "category")
@ManyToOne
private Category category;
@Expose
private boolean status;
@JoinColumn(name = "check")
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Check check;

@Entity
@Table(name = "checks")
public class Check {
@Id
@Expose
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
@Expose(serialize = false)
@Column(columnDefinition = "MEDIUMBLOB")
private byte[]data;
@Expose(serialize = false)
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "check")
private Ord order;

@Entity
@Table(name = "photos")
public class Photo {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Expose
private long id;
@Expose(serialize = false)
@Column(columnDefinition="mediumblob")
private byte[]data;
@Expose(serialize = false)
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "photo")
private Customer customer;
```

Comment: `order` зарезервированное слово в БД, попробуй `order1` сделать и напиши сюда

Comment: не, это я так написал просто...На самом деле Ord. Гляньте апдэйт, пожалуйста.

Comment: ну тогда добавь код своих сущностей без гет/сет, ну и сам стектрейс ошибки

Comment: @MrFylypenko которое без проблем экранируется, чем тулза уровня гибернейта не может не заниматься

Comment: @MrFylypenko добавил.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bigint, customer varchar(255), product varchar(255), primary key (id))' at line 1

Comment: С помощью `@JoinColumn(name = "check")` вы назвали поле в БД `check`, оно зарезервированное, попробуйте назвать его `check_id`

Comment: @MrFylypenko точно, забыл про check...Оформите ответ, я лайкну...Спасибо огромное, надо перерыв немного сделать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете зарезервированное слово `check` (оно не позволяет создать таблицу с таким столбцом) у связи для класса Check:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class Ord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "check_id") //вот тут замена
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Check check;

    //Другие поля
}
```

зарезервированное слово необходимо изменить на другое, например `check_id`.